# Как вывести значения ROWTYPE в CSV незная имён всех столбцов?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть процедура, которая использует представление для вывода в CSV файл всех записей этого представления. Но любой пользователь может изменить это представление, так что структура столбцов может часто меняться.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ выбрать все записи представления в коллекцию, и выводить элементы этой коллекции не указывая имна ВСЕХ столбцов?

Этot вопрос уже встаёт неоднократно, но не могу найти ответ на него, и должен изменять процедуру каждый раз, когда нужно выводить данные из изменённoго представление в CSV файл.

Фрагмент кода, который обычно использую для вывода, включает все имена столбцов:

```
PROCEDURE spoolToCSV is
    cursor c1 is
        select * from view1;
    TYPE alldata_typ IS table of c1%rowtype;
    v_dta alldata_typ;
BEGIN
    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CDMP_OUT_DIR', 'data.csv', 'W');
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, 'FSA_CODE,FSA_NAME,SERIES,VEHICLE_COUNT');
  
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_dta;
    FOR i IN 1..v_dta.count LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, 
        v_dta(i).fsa_code ||', '||
        v_dta(i).fsa_name ||', '||
        v_dta(i).series   ||', '||
        v_dta(i).vehicle_count);
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Print values of TABLE OF RECORDS TYPE without knowing the COLUMN NAMES of record](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63407578) от участника [@Swechchha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773650/swechchha)</sub>

Comment: кодогенератор сделать

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Сделал. Посмотрите пожалуйста, нигде не ошибся. Спасибо!

Comment: всегда рад, но в PL/SQL слаб; я всё больше перл-перлом генерю...

Answer (score 2):

Если используется `UTL_FILE`, то файл записывается на сервер БД. Если там нужен только CSV, то можно запускать команды SQL*Plus *непосредственно* из БД с помощью заданий планировщика.

Подробнее описал в [блоге - хороним UTL_FILE](https://connor-mcdonald.com/2018/06/20/the-death-of-utl_file/).

Но если кратко, то планировщик может запустить сессию SQL*Plus, которая имеет встроенную поддержку CSV формата для выводимого результата.

Вероятно, для больших объемов данных, это будет намного быстрее, чем `UTL_FILE`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446135) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Предложенное решение в ответе [@Connor McDonald](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1169258/217579) имеет один недостаток - выполняя непосредственно SQL*Plus команды, не удастся избавится от нежелательного вывода самого SQL*Plus, например, текста запроса или приглашения ввода.

Так как команды, которые могут подавить нежелательный вывод, доступны только при выполнении скрипта (`@, @@, start`), то необходимо выполнять цепочку команд в скрипте. Ниже рабочий пример, как надо сделать.

Создать примерно такой скрипт:

```
whenever oserror  exit failure;
whenever sqlerror exit failure;
define objname=&1
conn me/pass@localhost/pdb1
set markup csv on
set feed off termout off verify off
spool /tmp/&objname..csv
select * from &objname;
spool off
```

Тестовое представление и запуск задания:

```
create or replace view view1 as
    select level id, 'memo '||level memo, trunc (sysdate-3)+level dt
    from dual connect by level<=3 
/
declare
    script varchar2 (32767) := '@ /<абс. путь к скрипту>/spoolcsv view1';
    jobname varchar2 (30) := 'spoolCSV';
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (job_name=>jobname, job_type=>'SQL_SCRIPT',
        job_action=>script, credential_name=>'oscred', enabled=>true, auto_drop=>true);
end;
/
```

Содержимое созданного файла:

```
$ cat /tmp/view1.csv

"ID","MEMO","DT"
1,"memo 1","20200821T000000"
2,"memo 2","20200822T000000"
3,"memo 3","20200823T000000"
```

---

PS Данное решение с небольшими изменениями будет также работать на локальной машине. Воспользуйтесь планировщиком заданий, доступным в ОС на локальной машине.